# Add Grouping to LINQ Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I currently have a linq query that takes in a value from a date input in my View.

```
var applications = from s in db.ElmahErrors
                   where s.TimeUtc >= startDate && s.TimeUtc < endDate
                   select s;
```

So this query shows every error that took place on the day that is selected in the input.

A number of the errors are reoccurring errors that have the same Application name and Type. I am wanting to group these errors by their Application Name and Type so it just shows as a single row for each error.

I gave this a go already but it doesnt seem to like it.

## EDIT

```
var applications = from s in db.ElmahErrors
               where s.TimeUtc >= startDate && s.TimeUtc < endDate
               group s by new {s.Application, s.Type } into g
               select new ElmahError
               {
                   Application = g.Key,
                   Type = g.Key,
                   ErrorCount = g.Count()

               };
```

#### Model

```
[Table("ELMAH_Error")]
public class ElmahError
{
    [Key]
    public System.Guid ErrorId { get; set; }

    public System.String Application { get; set; }
    public System.String Host { get; set; }
    public System.String Type { get; set; }
    public System.String Source { get; set; }
    public System.String Message { get; set; }
    public System.String User { get; set; }
    public System.Int32 StatusCode { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime TimeUtc { get; set; }
    public System.Int32 Sequence { get; set; }
    public System.String AllXml { get; set; }

    public int ErrorCount { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try [group clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx)?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to _reduce_ the number of queried items? Grouping cannot _reduce_, but _group_ the items.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you field/property names here but this should work:

```
var applications = from s in db.ElmahErrors
                   where s.TimeUtc >= startDate && s.TimeUtc < endDate
                   group by new { s.Application, s.Type } into grp
                   select grp;
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is [group by](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx) clause:-

```
var ErrorsByapplications = from s in db.ElmahErrors
                   where s.TimeUtc >= startDate && s.TimeUtc < endDate
                   group s by new {s.ApplicationName, s.Type } into g
                   select new 
                     {
                        ApplicationName = g.Key,
                        Type = g.Key,
                        TotalErrors = g.Count()
                       ...and so on
                     };
```

**Update:**

If your `ElmahError` class already have properties like `ApplicationName`,`Type`, etc then you can project the same:-

```
group s by new {s.ApplicationName, s.Type } into g
select new ElmahError 
       {
           ApplicationName = g.Key,
           Type = g.Key,
           TotalErrors = g.Count() //If you have such property
           ErrorMessage = f.First().Errormessage //This will display only first 
                                          //error out of all (Consider checking for nulls)
        };
```

Comment: Do I need to change the model that is passed to the view `@model PagedList.IPagedList<DataIntelligence.Models.ElmahError>`

Comment: @D.M - It depends how `ElmahError` looks like. If you have property such as ApplicationName, Type etc. then you can project the same otherwise you have to. Please check my update.

Comment: @D.M - Did this helped you? Were you able to achieve what you were trying..?

Comment: No, I keep getting an error saying `Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'string'` on the lines where I try use `g.Key`

Comment: @D.M - Yeah that;'s because you must be projecting the anonymous type, use my Update code, if you have a class like `ElmahError` which can hold such property.

Comment: I am using that code and I do have a class that hold those property names, see edit

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ErrorsByapplications = from s in db.ElmahErrors
                           where s.TimeUtc >= startDate && s.TimeUtc < endDate
                           group s by new {s.Application, s.Type } into g
                           select new 
                           {
                              ApplicationName = g.Key,
                              Error = g.ToList()
                           };
```